# Changing css property in firefox developer console

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm having some trouble with CSS in Firefox.

Here his the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Fq4z/2/

The div with `.item-container` class should fill vertically it's parent (td). It does in chome and IE. But not in Firefox.

But there is a strange behavior. Step to reproduce:

- Open the fiddle in firefox
- Inspect element and select the div with the class `.item-container`
- change the `display` property to `inline-table` and press enter (it does not solve the problem)
- then change another time this property back to `inline-block` and press enter. It now shows up as it should...

Can anyone explain me why this happen and if possible, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It'l be better to use Firebug. After install right click on tag you want and in css section change values. With firebug you can run custom JS in your page.

Comment: With firebug the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Playing a bit with the height properties I came to the point that the problem might be with the  height being assigned using percentiles and considering you are using table it might be some kind of a bug with rendering in Firefox (I tested on 31 and 29 versions both).

I fixed some `heights` properties using pixels and forked the fiddle that might help you further

A possible workaround
http://jsfiddle.net/6Fq4z/3/

Comment: But I would like to have heights in percentage.